# Lithium Couchdb query design by key

Tags: php, cakephp, couchdb, lithium

This code is working fine:

```
$posts = Posts::all(array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'design' => 'posts', 'view' => 'all',
        'limit' => 10, 'descending' => 'true'
    )
));
```

It queries all Posts documents.

But when you use filter by key it doesn't work:

```
$posts = Posts::all(array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'design' => 'posts', 'view' => 'all',
        'key' => 'title',
        'limit' => 10, 'descending' => 'true'
    )
));
```

Any ideas on how to filter design document by key?

**Update:**

This query works fine: 'key' => '"title"' with double quote

```
$posts = Posts::all(array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'design' => 'posts', 'view' => 'all',
        'key' => '"title"',
        'limit' => 10, 'descending' => 'true'
    )
));
```

Comment: It works with with double quote: 'key' => '"title"'. I'll delete this question or mark it as solve

Comment: You can also answer your own question. I don't think this is expected behavior though.